# How does fstrim not suffer from race conditions?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, race-condition

It is my understanding that the `fstrim` utility on GNU/Linux is just a utility, not a kernel module; how does it avoid race conditions between finding out that a given block is unused and issuing the [ioctl(2)](http://mdoc.su/-/ioctl.2) `FITRIM` command to TRIM it?

- http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/fstrim.8.html

Answer (score 0):

This is easily answered by reading the source.

The [`fstrim` utility](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/util-linux/blob/403826bef03b521b323f3c778c76b18a8a43e363/sys-utils/fstrim.c) has nothing to do with figuring out which blocks are used or unused, and has no code for doing anything of the sort.  It simply invokes the `FITRIM` ioctl on the entire range of the device specified by the `-o` and `-l` options, or by default, the whole device ([`start = 0, len = ULLONG_MAX`](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/util-linux/blob/403826bef03b521b323f3c778c76b18a8a43e363/sys-utils/fstrim.c#L401)).  It's understood that the kernel should only trim the *unused* blocks in that range, and it is up to the kernel to figure out which blocks those are, locking as appropriate.  As you say, it would be nearly impossible to do this from user space without risking races or deadlocks.

[Here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/a2d79c7174aeb43b13020dd53d85a7aefdd9f3e5/fs/ext4/mballoc.c#L5153) is the kernel code that handles trim for ext4.  I am not an expert on fs code, but it seems clear that some sort of locking is taking place.